# Help with syntax and adding a table and conditions to a query

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

switch($_GET["action"])
{
case "add_item":
{
AddItem($_GET["idc"], $_GET["qty"]);
ShowCart();
break;
}
case "update_item":
{
UpdateItem($_GET["idc"], $_GET["qty"]);
ShowCart();
break;
}
case "remove_item":
{
RemoveItem($_GET["idc"], $_GET["id"]);
ShowCart();
break;
}
default:
{
ShowCart();
}
}
function AddItem($itemId, $qty){


$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE cookieId = '" . GetCartId() . "' AND id = $itemId");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numRows = $row[0];

if($numRows == 0)
{
// This item doesn't exist in the users cart,
// we will add it with an insert query

mysql_query("INSERT INTO cart(cookieId, id, qty) values('" . GetCartId() . "', $itemId, $qty)");
//printf ("Inserted records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

}
else
{
// This item already exists in the users cart,
// we will update it instead
 mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET qty = $qty WHERE cookieId = '" . GetCartId() . "' AND id = $itemId");

}

}

function UpdateItem($itemId, $qty)
{

mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET qty = $qty WHERE cookieId = '" . GetCartId() . "' AND id = $itemId");
//printf ("Updated records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

}

function RemoveItem($itemId) 
{

mysql_query("DELETE FROM cart WHERE cookieId = '" . GetCartId() . "' AND id = $itemId");
}

?>

<?php 
function ShowCart()

{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
                  cart.id         cart_id,
                  cart.id         cart_id,
                  cart.cartId     cartId,
                  cart.cookieId   cookie_Id,
                  cart.qty        qt_y,                     
                  cdkb.id         cdkb_id,
                  cdkb.name       name,
                  cdkb.image      image,
                  cdkb.price      price,
                  dkb.id          dkb_id,
                  dkb.name        name1, 
                  dkb.image       image1,
                  dkb.price       price2,
                  dbl.product_id  product_id,
              dbl.price       price3,
              dbl.variety     variety,
              dbl.description description                  
FROM
        cart


        LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
           ON cart.id = cdkb.id    

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
           ON cart.id = dkb.id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbl
           ON dbl.id = dkb.id 


    WHERE
        cart.cookieId ='" . GetCartId() . "' ' ORDER BY cdkb.name AND dkb.name ASC");

    <div id="cart">
<div id="group">
<div id="quantity">Qty</div>
<div id="cartpic">Pic</div>
<div id="product">Product</div>
<div id="cartprice">Price</div>
<div id="remove">Remove</div>
</div>
<?php

$totalCost=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
// Increment the total cost of all items
$totalCost += ($row["qt_y"] * $row["price1"]);

?>

<div id="cart1">
<select name="<?php echo $row["ckb_id"];?>" onChange="UpdateQty(this)">
<?php  print($row["ckb_id"]);?>
<?php

for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++)
{
echo "<option ";
if($row["qt_y"] == $i)
{
echo " SELECTED ";
}
echo ">" . $i . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div id="cart2">
<img src="images/logopic.gif"<?php /*?><?php echo $row["image1"]; ?><?php */?> alt="we" width="60" height="50" />
</div>
<div id="cart3"><p><?php echo $row["dishname1"]; ?></p></div>



<div id="cart4"><p>
$<?php echo number_format($row["price3"], 2, ".", ","); ?></p></div>

<div id="cart5">
<p><?php
printf('<a href="cart.php?action=remove_item&id=%d&idc=%d&register=%s">Remove</a>', $_GET['id'], $row['ckb_id'], $_GET['register']);
?></p></div>

<hr size="1" color="red" >

<script language="JavaScript">

function UpdateQty(item)
{
itemId = item.name;
newQty = item.options[item.selectedIndex].text;

document.location.href = 'cart.php?action=update_item&id='+itemId+'&qty='+newQty;
}

</script>





<?php
}
?>

<font face="verdana" size="2" color="black" style="clear:right;">
<b>Total: $<?php echo number_format($totalCost, 2, ".", ","); ?></b></font></td>


<?php
}
?>
```

Above is the updated code and query of the cart.php. If you notice below the query there is a while loop. Right now the while loop is perfectly set up for dkb table which are items coming from page1.php. this loop is set up in a way that it will repeat save, display and manage ecah item qty, image, name, price and remove options, display them and repeat them as many items the user chooses. Well that fields set up and design doesn't quite work from items coming from page2.php which the information displayed in the cart gets pull up from the tables dkb and dbl. The problem right now is that when coming from page2.php to the cart the same item name repeats three times because in the dbl table the design is as follows.

```
INSERT INTO `dbl` (`id`, `price`, `variety`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 20.30, 'Small Tray', 'Serves 6 to 8 people' ),
(1, 25.90, 'Medium Tray', 'Serves 12 to 15 people'),
(1, 30.90, 'Large Tray', 'Serves 18 to 21 people'),
(136, 0.00, 'Small Tray', '', 'small'),
(136, 0.00, 'Medium Tray', '' ),
(136, 0.00, 'Large Tray', ''),
(2, 0.00, 'Small Tray', ''),
(2, 0.00, 'Medium Tray', ''),
(2, 0.00, 'Large Tray', '');
```

The insert above suppose to be three items of dkb see the dbl.id it joins on dkb.id in the query dbl.id=dkb.id Well dbl.id has three prices for one item in dkb table which in this case is three prices for item 1, three for item 136 and three prices for item 2. So it is three different variety, and descriptions for each one of those items in dkb. From now and on if you take a look at the fields assign in the while loop below the query some of them are of the dkb others from the cdkb and dbl. Rigth now as I said some where above the set up in the while loop is ok from information coming from the dkb table which only will have one price, and one name. Some what I am thinking is to arrange an if statement condition to detect where the information is coming from page1.php which is the one name and price or from page2.php which is going to be one name, from one to three prices and varieties depending on the small, medium or large tray the user chooses. Which each tray carry a price but it will be one name name 1, 136, or 2 which those are the id coming from dkb table. In the if statement inside the while loop to display the information from page2.php that require from one to three prices and variety will have a foreach loop or maybe a for loop don't know to count how many variety the user choose in page2.php to display it inside the while loop in cart with the help of an if statment that will detect weather it was choosen from page1.php or page2.php.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM .... LEFT OUTER JOIN .... WHERE") // This is the query we have discussed in this forum.
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  if($row['cdkb_id']){
echo "<div>qty</div>";
echo"<div>". $row['image'] . "</div>";
echo"<div>". $row['name'] . "</div>";
echo"<div>". $row['price'] . "</div>";
echo"<div>remove</div>";
}
else{
echo "<div>qty</div>";
echo"<div>". $row['image1'] . "</div>";
echo"<div>". $row['name1'] . "</div>";
foreach ($row['dkb_id'] as $variety) {
echo"<div>".$variety['variety']. $variety['price3'] . "</div>";
// the vriety and price3 field will display three times as in table dbl has three prices and three variety. It is correct to use a foreach loop for  in this case?}
echo"<div>remove</div>"; 
// end of foreach loop inside the else statement
}// end of if else statement
}// end of while loop
?>
```

So the final display and illustration to be search and present as a final product is as below, That's the desired look.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
if (table cdkb) { 
  [1]qyt         image      name          price        remove
     1            ---       marina        $18.90        remove?    
     }end of if statement
Else table dkb {
   1]qyt            Image         Name             Price                  Remove
     1               ---         marina         Small Tray  $18.90        remove? 
                                                Medium Tray $30.24
                                                Large Tray  $35.90
                  } // end of else statement

                  }//end of while loop
```

Give me a final hand on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the selects individually and then table.* that is probably your problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM
cart

LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
   ON cart.id = dkb.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
   on cart.id = cdkb.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN double
   on cart.id = double.id
WHERE 
cart.cookieId = GetCartId() AND cdkb.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The first outer join dkb I want to display ON cart.id= dkb.id WHERE dkb.id =$idc

and the second outer join cdkb to display ON cart.id= dkb.id WHERE dkb.id =$id


$idc comes from the url of page1.php to cart.php and $id comes from the url of page2.php to cart.php....
 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb ON cart.id= dkb.id WHERE dkb.id = $id

LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb ON cart.id = cdkb.id WHERE cdkb.id= $idc

WHERE 
cart.cookieId = GetCartId()

Comment: So I think that instead of dkb.id then $idc should be in that place like 

ON cart.id = $idc

Comment: What the IS NOT NULL Means in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To set up some data for this query for MySQL:

```
-- **********************************************************************
-- Table holding all the items in the users shopping cart, along with
-- a cookieId for thier session
-- **********************************************************************
Create table cart
   (
   cartId           integer,
   cookieId         integer,
   id               integer,
   qty              integer
   )
go

-- **********************************************************************
-- Table all the items available for sale with the price
-- **********************************************************************
Create table dkb
   (
   id               integer,
   name             varchar(20),
   price            decimal(12,2)
   )
go

-- **********************************************************************
-- Table that looks like the items table, but we have no idea why it is
-- here.
-- **********************************************************************
Create table cdkb
   (
   id               integer,
   name             varchar(20),
   price            decimal(12,2)
   )
go

-- **********************************************************************
-- Another table with a price in it .. a completely different id field
-- and a variety ... WTH is it for - No idea.
-- **********************************************************************
Create table dblv
   (
   dbl_id           integer,
   price            decimal(12,2),
   variety          varchar(20)
   )
go

insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 1, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 2, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 3, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 4, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 5, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 6, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 7, 1);
go
insert into cart (cartid, cookieid, id, qty) values (1, 1, 8, 1);
go

insert into dkb (id, name, price) values (1,'my dkb 1', 10.00);
go
insert into dkb (id, name, price) values (2,'my dkb 2', 20.00);
go
insert into dkb (id, name, price) values (3,'my dkb 3', 30.00);
go
insert into dkb (id, name, price) values (4,'my dkb 4', 40.00);
go

insert into cdkb (id, name, price) values (5,'my cdkb 5', 50.00);
go
insert into cdkb (id, name, price) values (6,'my cdkb 6', 60.00);
go
insert into cdkb (id, name, price) values (7,'my cdkb 7', 70.00);
go
insert into cdkb (id, name, price) values (8,'my cdkb 8', 80.00);
go

insert into dblv (dbl_id, price, variety) values (1,1.99,'my dbl 1 variety');
go
insert into dblv (dbl_id, price, variety) values (2,1.99,'my dbl 2 variety');
go
```

then the results of this query:

```
SELECT
   cart.id    cart_id,
   dkb.id     dkb_id,
   cdkb.id    cdkb_id,
   cart.*,
   dkb.*,
   cdkb.*,
   dblv.*
FROM
    cart

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb
       ON cart.id = dkb.id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dblv
       on dkb.id = dblv.dbl_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdkb
       on cart.id = cdkb.id
```

results show up as:

```
cart_id    dkb_id     cdkb_id    cartId     cookieId   id         qty        id         name                 price        id         name                 price        dbl_id     price        variety              
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------- ------------ -------------------- 
1          1          NULL       1          1          1          1          1          my dkb 1             10.00        NULL       NULL                 NULL         1          1.99         my dbl 1 variety     
2          2          NULL       1          1          2          1          2          my dkb 2             20.00        NULL       NULL                 NULL         2          1.99         my dbl 2 variety     
3          3          NULL       1          1          3          1          3          my dkb 3             30.00        NULL       NULL                 NULL         NULL       NULL         NULL                 
4          4          NULL       1          1          4          1          4          my dkb 4             40.00        NULL       NULL                 NULL         NULL       NULL         NULL                 
5          NULL       5          1          1          5          1          NULL       NULL                 NULL         5          my cdkb 5            50.00        NULL       NULL         NULL                 
6          NULL       6          1          1          6          1          NULL       NULL                 NULL         6          my cdkb 6            60.00        NULL       NULL         NULL                 
7          NULL       7          1          1          7          1          NULL       NULL                 NULL         7          my cdkb 7            70.00        NULL       NULL         NULL                 
8          NULL       8          1          1          8          1          NULL       NULL                 NULL         8          my cdkb 8            80.00        NULL       NULL         NULL
```

sorry not much time today - long day at work. :-)  I'll check back tomorrow ..

Comment: Before I post the tables structures I want to add that double table is join on dlb.id = dkb.id as you post it and will display its table information together with dkb table. Both of them need to be on since they are displaying information together.

Comment: Look at the first post I have edited and I have post the complete query with the field names.

Comment: Exactly, because you wanted it to be only displayed if cart.id = dkb.id ... so it is really JOINed to dkb.id. :-)

Comment: your last comment was in reference to my last to the first comment after your answer post or the edit of the first post I did?

Comment: In reference to the first comment above. :-) Anyway, appears your problem is solved!

Comment: I just have to test it now, I wanted to do the final retouch theoretically speaking. Now I have to go and do the work. Thank you Ron

Comment: how can you echo the query so the dynamics can be seen?
I have used $result = mysql_query("SELECT.....")

Comment: Ron check the first post for some edit work I have added '".$ids."' and '".$idc."' so the syntax can be fixed. But then the query is not display the information nof dkb ON dkb.id = '".$ids."' as well as cdkb.id = '".$idc."'.

Comment: @Ron I have re-edited the first post again and added some php and html code in the first post and some explanation on why the cart won't display the name of the item and the price as well?

Ron I have created another question just because it seems you are sleeping, not ignoring your knowledge but for speed purposes But I will appreciate you still having an opinion after you come back in the morning thanks you!

Comment: Ron any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Hello Ron any opinions on his take brother! i am drowning on an sql error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cart LEFT OUTER JOIN dkb ON (cart.id = dkb.i' at line 21

Don't know where is coming from everything aparently seem to be ok. but not. Give me a hand here

Comment: @Ron 
I haven't test your new changes, But I have to say that the query cdkb table that looks like the item tables has exactly the same fields of the items tables, its like a second items table the thing is that I have done like that because of a design clash. For instance I have a table that has menu subjects names another that has the submenus subjects. let's say that the menu subjects has 5 subjects then the first menu subject and the fourth emnu subject in my case uses the same submenu subjects but with variation on design because both menu sujects first and fourth handle diferent menu ->

Comment: subjects. handle same subemnu suject but diferent submenu design. But the issue is not the diferent menu subject, or having the same submenu subject or having diferent submenu design in part but no puting two different relational ids in one field. For instance I can not assign two id to the same field in order to direct the database to recognize that first submenu subject is for this menu subject and the other relational foreign key for the second submenu suject. In order for me to acheive that I would have to do a many to many relation ship and assign two different submenus subjects --->

Comment: to one menu subjec. Well since I had quite bit of data right now I have decided to take the approach of LEFT OUTER JOIN two different tables similar in content which are dkb and cdkb tables. since dkb is different in css and html design and require more data and in this case coming from another table I have wanted to have dbl tables double table to dump data together with dkb since those data goes together in one page and they depend on another to satisfied page2.php which require data and information from those two tables.

Comment: I think that the design of having a many to many relationship to have several submenu subjects to one menu subject was quite a good idea but it would be crazy too redesign the some tables that has a quite a bit of information.

Comment: hope I have clarified your concerns in your last design you have put up. Have to say that the price in dkb won't be use since I use the price field of the dbl table that combine together with dkb to display it's content. The price field in dkb still there because I have made a copy pf cdkb and I have forgot to erase the price field which I won't use since page2.php uses dbl price field to show up the prices of the items inside dkb.

Comment: @Ron your edited query worked... Some new issues arises now ï will post them later.

Thank you Ron

Comment: @Ron I have edited the script above with some issues that has come to present afterward.